# Cannot download laravel/socialite package in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

> [ErrorException]
> file_put_contents(/home/webwerks/.cache/composer/repo/https---repo.packagis
> t.org/provider-psr~http-client.json): failed to open stream: Permission den
> ied

Answer (score 0):

#### You have a Permission denied problem

move to your project directory

## Solution A

run  `sudo composer update` on the terminal

## Solution B

fix the owner and Permission to everyone to this folder `/home/webwerks/.cache`

## Solution C

Delete `/home/webwerks/.cache` by running `sudo rm -rf /home/webwerks/.cache` on the terminal
then re composer the project by running  `composer install`

and Welcome to our community @anmol :)

Comment: Thank you it worked I tried it with sudo chown -R $USER ~/.config/composer to provide write access